# Constant time to access first and last node

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, queue

How would you modify a linked list based queue so that first and last node can be accessed in a constant time regardless of data nodes in queue?

Answer (score 0):

You will keep two pointers/reference variables, one for head of queue and other for tail. When you insert an item, you will set the tail to last inserted item, and when you remove an item, your head will obviously go to next item in queue.  Since you have two variables for head and tail, it will be a constant time operation to access them.

This is the general way to create a queue with linked list itself, this will be needed to insert items and remove items from queue, nothing special here.